# Select no banco access

Tags: vb.net

Estou com dificuldade para pegar dados do banco.
Consigo inserir no meu banco com esse codigo

```
    Dim comandosql As OleDbCommand
    cadastro = "Insert INTO usuarios (usuario, senha) Values ('" & TextBox1.Text & "','" & TextBox2.Text & "')"
    comandosql = New OleDbCommand(cadastro, conexao)
    comandosql.ExecuteNonQuery()
    MsgBox("Dados inseridos com sucesso")
```

Agora eu queria selecionar os dados já cadastrados, por exemplo procurar na tabela usuarios o "codigo" = 1 e selecionar o "usuario" e "senha" deste codigo e fazer ele aparecer nos textbox3 e textbox4

Alguem poderia me ajudar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Levando em consideração que você estará buscando estes dados de um unico usuario você pode usar o seguinte código:

```
Dim comandosql as OleDbCommand
Dim reader As OleDbDataReader = Nothing
busca = "Select senha from usuarios where usuario = " & Textbox3.Text
comandosql = New OleDbCommand(busca, conexao)
reader = comandosql.Executereader()
TextBox4.Text = reader.Read()
read.Close()
```

Assim você busca a senha do usuario.
Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Entendi o seu código, ajudou muito. Obrigado pela ajuda!